# Whats the best pratice to create constant variables and subclasses inhertience them

Tags: java, constants, extends

I am not sure if there is a standard or good practice to create the constant variables in the parent class, and then subclasses reuse.

```
public class parentA{
protected static final String name = Constants.SYS_NAME;
protected static final String code = Constants.CODE;
```

}

```
public class son extends parentA{

private static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Name: "+name); 
        System.out.println("Code: "+code ); 
    } 

}
```

Comment: Is there a better practice?

Answer (score 2):

A common practice is to use an [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) for constants.

```
interface MyInterface {
    public static final int X = 10;
    public static final int Y = 20;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MyInterface.X);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
10
```

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/reasons-why-the-constant-interface-pattern-is-disc

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - Thanks for sharing this link. I'll go through it.